# Can ASP.NET control be used in WinForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

This is probably a stupid question, but I have to ask.

I found this excellent (and mainly free) control suite (Ext.NET) and I wonder if it's possible to use it in WinForms.

If it can, is it something normally doable or would it be a nightmare?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but have you tried yourself? Beats waiting for an answer from someone else.

Comment: Maybe if you created an HTML control on a page and then ran a local web server in your app and browsed pages there you could do it.  Sounds like a nightmare though...

Comment: I have tried it myself, but I wasn't sure if it was a failure on my part or if it simply cannot be done.

Comment: You can however host Winforms controls in ASP.NET pages according to: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The life cycle and environment of ASP.NET controls is very different from normal desktop controls and there's no way to interchange them.

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible with any straight forward solution, Asp.net control would be using `System.Web.UI control` whereas Window `System.Windows.Forms Controls`.

Comment: It's a shame, I doubt I'll ever find any free control suite for Winforms as complete and as appealing.